# Dump remote mysql database with compatibility with postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to copy data from a table named references which is in a remote database, after some googles, i found that i could do this using:

```
mysqldump -u root -h <host> -p <db_name> references > references.sql
```

i tried and it works, but i also want to set `--compatible=postgresql`, the problem is when i do that, it gives me the following error:

```
Invalid mode to --compatible: postgresql
```

How can i dump from a remote database but at the same time use `--compatible=postgres`?

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

> --compatible=name

No `:`. It is amazing what the docs can teach you.

Comment: ':' is what the error gives me, but i actually used exactly what you said in your answer 
(--compatible=name)

Comment: What version of `MySQL`? What is the actual complete command line?

Comment: Look like `ansi` is only option in `MySQL 8.0`. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible). I can get it to work with `MariaDB 10.2` though.